# pull data from csv file and submit each row to url with curl

Tags: php, curl

I am looking for guidance on the following code. I have numerous large CSV files that are in the format of

```
firstname,lastname,address,state,zip,email,homephone,dob,optindate,ipaddress,url
Joey,Demo,4004 S. Louise Ave. 206,Sioux Falls,SD,57106,jdemo@hotmail.com,6053231657,06/18/1944,4/19/2008 11:58:34,12.174.252.216,http://www.ecoupons.com
```

I am trying to add a few new variables, convert the data to a http_build_query and submit each row to a url with POST.

Here is my code

```
$processid = '123454r4rt5rt5rtr';
$version = '1.0.0';
$partnercode = 'ABC';
$listid = 'ID12345';

$fp= fopen("test.csv", "r");

while (!feof($fp) ) {
     list($firstname,$lastname,$address,$city,$state,$zip,$email,$phone,$dob,$optindate,$ipaddress,$url) = fgetcsv($fp);
$data = array('firstname' => $firstname,
'lastname' => $lastname,
'address' => $address,

'city' => $city,
'state' => $state,
'zip' => $zip,
'email' => $email,
'homephone' => $phone,
'dob' => $dob,
'optindate' => $optindate,
'ipaddress' => $ipaddress,

    'url' => $url,
    'processid' => $partnercode,
    'version' => $version,
    'partnercode' => $partnercode,
    'listid' => $listid);

    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://localhost.com');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'usernameassword')

$data = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);
```

When I am testing right now I keep getting  unexpected T_VARIABLE but I am not 100% sure my coding is correct.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error you are getting is a syntax error.  Possible you forgot to terminate a line with a semi-colon

Answer (score 1):

`curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'usernameassword')` should be `curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'usernameassword');` with semi-colon at the end.

Comment: @gar- Take care of your syntax errors first.  If you still have problems come post the issue here.  We are not going to debug your code for you error by error.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you left out a semi-colon on the line containing

`curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'usernameassword')`

The next line of code is the definition of a variable but since the previous line is not terminated the PHP interpreter encounters an unexpected variable - `$data`.

Add the additional semi-colon and please fix your syntax errors before posting your questions here.  The error most likely contained the line number that the error was occurring on.

When dealing with these sorts of errors you always need to look at the surrounding code for errors as well - they might be the underlying cause.

Comment: Thanks for catching that missing semi-colon. When I stare at code too long it all blends together. I can work thru the file now but get the following error that I need to trackdown. curl_setopt() expects exactly 3 parameters, 2 given in /tmp/curl.php on line 36
which is the curlopt_userpwd

Answer (score 0):

Your CSV file contains only 11 columns, but your PHP code expects 12 columns (looks like the `city` column is missing).

That could be the reason.

Comment: In the csv, state comes after address, but in the code `list(...)` has city between address and state. Also, missing semi-colon after 'curl_setopt(CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'usernameassword')`;