# PHP - Read every line in a CSV, take the data and Post/CURL each line one by one

Tags: php, csv, curl

I have about 14,000 lines in a CSV file.

Each line is formatted like this:

```
Firstname Lastname,UUID
Firstname Lastname,UUID
```

I want to Post/CURL to a url like:

```
http://some.url/directory/file.php?name=Firstname%20Lastname&uuid=UUID
```

I have tried doing this a few ways, but I always run into an issue - what's a good way to do this, and I don't want to attack the URL by sending 14,000 requests at once.

I do not need any data back from each posting, I just need to send the data over to the PHP file so it can be analyzed.

NOTE: Each post means a mysql query will be analyzing the data, so I don't want to flood the server with 14,000 mysql requests at once either - more reason why I might want to throttle this.

I just have to do this one time ever.

Would something like [pull data from csv file and submit each row to url with curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481087/pull-data-from-csv-file-and-submit-each-row-to-url-with-curl) be a good place to start?

Comment: one at a time with a pause `sleep(1);` between each.

Comment: Maybe you should talk to the web site operator, find out if there's a way you could access the database directly instead of going through the URL once for each name.

Comment: The data i'm importing needs to be screened to make sure it's not in there already, else i'll have duplicates. The URL i'm trying to hit filters to make sure the data does not already exist.

Comment: other than loop-hit,pause,hit - thers not much more to say (run in background, keep track, in case something fails you wont want to start at the beginning every time)